# Understanding of back end file seeding to provide fast client downloads

Tags: java, file-upload, client-server, download, backend

The theme of my project is to implement a distributed server which provides several clients several files to download. The server is hosting several files and we want that the server should implement some best algorithms to quickly let the clients download data from it.

My idea of implementation of project:

Like the client generally downloads the file using some download managers, similarly there must exist some server side managers/codes/algorithms which upload/seed the file quickly to let client download the file. *There must not be any action of client except the selection of the file to be downloaded!*

How should I write the code for such a server on the back end, analogous to multi-threading based downloaded managers for clients on the front-end?

How should server seed/make avail the file to the client if the client only sends the path as a String to the server in Java for downloading?

Or, if I am missing something/my idea is totally wrong, please enlighten me with an alternative process/algorithm which I must implement on the server side. Please remember that the whole purpose of asking this question is the back end server seeding algorithm OR equivalent algorithms/methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, this server of yours has a good internet connection with a broad upstream. If that is the case then the limiting factor when only few clients are downloading few files is the bandwith of these clients. So you will at most get as fast as the downstream bandwith of your clients. So simply taking an off-the-shelf HTTP server library to serve the downloads should be sufficient.

Where your backend implementation really matters and is able to improve download performance is then many users are connecting to your server and downloading many files. First off there are following points to consider:

- TCP has a startup-time. When you first open an connection, the download rate slowly starts to increase until it hits the maximum. To minimize this time, when downloading multiple files the connection opened for one file download should be reused for the next file.
- Downloading many files at once(on clientside) is not reasonable when bandwidth is the limiting factor, because the client has to start up many TCP connections and the data will be either fragmented, when written to Disk, or (when allocating beforehand) the disk will be pretty busy while jumping between sectors.
- Your server should generally use a non-blocking IO library (eg. [java.nio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_(Java))) and refrain from creating a thread per incomming connection since this leads to [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)) which again decreases your server's performance drastically.

If you have a really big amount of clients simultaneously downloading from your server, the limit you will probably hit will be either:

- The upstream limit of your provider
- The read speed of your Harddrive (SSD have ~ 500MB/s as far as I'm informed)

Your server can try to hold the most commonly requested files in his memory and serve the content from there ([DDR3 RAM reaches speeds of 17GB/s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM)). I doubt that you have only as few files on your server that you could cache them all in your server's RAM.

So the main engineering task lays in the clever selection of which content should be cached and which not. This could be done on a priority base by assigning higher priorities to certain files or by a metric which encodes the probability of a single file to be downloaded in the next few minutes. Or simply the files which are downloaded by the most clients at this point of time.

With such considerations you are able to push the limits of your download server until a certain point from which the only improvement can be achieved by distributing or replicating your files onto many servers.

If you are going into such a direction where serving millions of clients simultaneously must be possible, you should consider buying such a service from CDNs. They are specialized in fast delivery and have many upstream server in most ASes so that every client can download his files from the regional CDN server.

---

I know, I haven't given any algorithm or code examples, but I didn't intend to answer this question completely. I just wnated to give you some important guidelines and thoughts to that topic. I hope, you can at least use some of these thoughts for your project.

Comment: Please check this and reply---http://mailinator.blogspot.in/2008/02/kill-myth-please-nio-is-not-faster-than.html . If satisfied,I'll upvote your answer,and also later reward bounty to you!

Comment: I'm not really convinced with their results. I believe that they really have measured these results and that they are not made up. But programming with NIO is much more complex than using vanilla blocking IO. Since I don't have insight into their code, I can't verify that these tests were fair. A second thing that stung me is that they made measurements only for exact 1700 concurrecnt connections. I'm pretty sure, blocking IO will get problematic when going further up and it will go further up(next comment)

Comment: So,as per you isn't 1700 concurrent connections convincing? I am with them as it seems legitimate enough and no one would have tried more connections!

Comment: Their setup was pretty convenient for showing how well IO outperfroms NIO by limiting concurrent connections to 1700 and just measuring throughput. But in your case if many clients will download concurrently files and these files may be large, then each connection will be open for a long time. As I said, I don't know what clients you are serving, but average internet users have a pretty rough bandwidth limit and throughput should't be your main concern. Instead you will have to serve thousands of open (slow)connections simultaneously and having this many threads impacts server performance...

Comment: @shekharsuman regarding your comment: It is just convincing for that number. I don't like the general statement "blocking IO is better than NIO" resulting of one specific setup. 

If you aim to provide a server whose focus isn't on serving thousands of clients simultaneously then blocking IO should do fine in your case.

Comment: Thanks,let me try your suggestion. Your award is waiting for you!

Comment: Might also interest you: I found a [scientific work from 2011](http://repository.wit.ie/1636/1/Scaling_Instant_Messaging_Communication_Services.pdf), which shows how a non-blocking NodeJS application outperforms a Java and a Scala application with a seven times higher message throughput.