# Multithreading using Blocking IO corrupts file in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, file, client-server, blocking

**AIM :-** TO build a multithreading application using Blocking IO in Java to download a file. **Please don't suggest me to use Non-Blocking IO**, I have been told to use this one.

**Issue :-** My code works fine on a client machine which downloads a file hosted on a server. But, the issue is my Server seeds the file using multiple threads. In all the cases, the file received is of exact length,but, the file appears corrupted. Like, when I download a PDF file, the file pages are halfway written to the last(means all pages are filled with partial content of the original). When I download a song, it is bursted throughout & plays till last with those noise bits.

**Question 1 :-** How should I maintain the perfect smooth downloading so that the file plays/opens/reads properly? What technique like issues because of multithreading should I resolve here?

My Code :-

Server Multi-threading code ::::

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
public class FileServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements FileServerInitialise{

private String file="";
public FileServer() throws RemoteException{
    super();
}

public void setFile(String f){
    file=f;
    //System.out.println("Length in setFile = "+f);
}

@Override
public boolean login(FileClientInitialise fci) throws RemoteException {
    try {
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        long len = new File(file).length();
        System.out.println("Length of File = "+len);
        WorkerThread wt1=new WorkerThread(0,len/2,fci,is,file);
        wt1.setName("Worker Thread 1");
        WorkerThread wt2=new WorkerThread(len/2+1,2*len/2,fci,is,file);
        wt2.setName("Worker Thread 2");
        //WorkerThread wt3=new WorkerThread(2*len/4+1,3*len/4,fci,is,file);
        //wt3.setName("Worker Thread 3");
        //WorkerThread wt4=new WorkerThread(3*len/4+1,len,fci,is,file);
        //wt4.setName("Worker Thread 4");
        wt1.start();
        wt2.start();
        //wt3.start();
        //wt4.start();
        wt1.join();
        wt2.join();
        //wt3.join();
        //wt4.join();
        return true;
    }
        catch (InterruptedException iex) {          
        iex.getMessage();
        return false;
        }
```

Client Downloading code ::::

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class FileClient implements FileClientInitialise {
public static int count = 1;
public static File f;
public static FileOutputStream fos;
public static RandomAccessFile raf;
public static long pointer;

public FileClient (String filename) throws RemoteException, IOException {
super();
FileClient.f= new File(filename);
FileClient.fos = new FileOutputStream(f, true);
//FileClient.raf= new RandomAccessFile(f,"rwd");
FileClient.pointer=0;
}

@Override
public boolean sendData(String filename, byte[] data, int len, String threadName) throws RemoteException{
try{

FileClient.fos.write(data,0,len);
FileClient.fos.flush();
//FileClient.raf.seek(FileClient.pointer);
//FileClient.raf.write(data,0, len);
//FileClient.pointer=raf.getFilePointer();
System.out.println("Done writing data...");
//fos.close();
return true;

}catch(Exception e){
e.getMessage();
return false;
}
}
}
```

**Question 2 :-** Also, should I use `RandomAccessFile` to achieve the same? Would it be more better? I checked it and it works very slow(almost 10 times slower). And, if I were to use `RandomAccessFile`, should I create a separate object for each thread? How should I use it, if advised in this case?

If code isn't possible, please give me a technical description, the code isn't necessary to be mentioned in the answer.

Comment: If you use Java 7+ use java.nio.file instead; you'll have a much easier time achieving what you want

Comment: Your attempt is terrible. Since you're reading the whole file, the fastest way is to just read it with a single thread. It also looks like you're attempting to share the `FileInputStream` with multiple threads, which is a very bad idea. Forget multithreading, this is not the correct place for it.

Comment: @Kayaman- How should I allow writing the outputstream using multiple threads, I could think only of this? And, I'd request to add an answer as you already got my point. And, please elaborate the corrupt-file case too.

Comment: *"How should I allow writing the outputstream using multiple threads"*.  You shouldn't.  It is unlikely to improve performance,

Comment: @StephenC-Sorry to argue,but, then how does IDM and other multithreaded softwares,etc. work? Means only client threading works, what if I want servers to seed using multiple threads. Please check this question --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615545/java-understanding-of-back-end-server-side-file-seeding-to-provide-fast-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already mentioned in the comments, this is a poor approach to allow input streams to be shared by multiple threads and allow concurrent writing, which results in corruption of file.

One approach which I performed in my multithreaded distributed file-server project was that I allowed the multi-threaded execution of the file-server, but only sequential thread execution.

I coded in such a way to ensure that the threads access the input-stream in a synchronised way,only one by one manner. This didn't corrupt the file either at the client side. And, this was performance effective too amazingly.

***NOTE, before taking any action on this answer :-***

I did benchmarking of codes at that time to ensure that what I have stated in this answer really is optimal for the visitors/seekers. This I believe was the optimal case also because I had 4 logical processors(cores/CPU) which reduced the overhead of multiple threads(though they all working 1 at a time).

People would argue that this is worst approach,OR an ugly approach,etc. But I found this very helpful in the file-server seeding. My 40 MB(approximately) of PDF file on ***`Linux Server [Intel(R) Core(TM) 2 Duo CPU E4600 @ 2.40GHz processor, CPU(s): 2]`*** was copied to the file-client in almost 33-34 seconds on an average in 4-5 execution tests. Whereas, when I increased the number of threads(8-10 threads), the performance decreased taking about 36-38 seconds. Same was the case when I had the single-threaded server, in which the same file was copied in 45-50 seconds. With increase in the number of threads, the performance improved and it was efficient in the range of 4-6 threads.

Though, there would obviously be overhead of maintaining so many threads, and people would have thought that a single thread could win, **BUT, SURPRISINGLY,**  the result was optimal in case of 4-6 threads.

So, my suggestion is to proceed as shown in the code by performing sequential accessing of input-streams by 4-6 threads. This is optimal, and believe me, I can argue with others too about multi-threads overheading which I found optimal in case of 4-6 threads.

For your code, I'd suggest the following change :-

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        long len = new File(file).length();
        System.out.println("Length of File = "+len);
        int numOFThreads=4;
        WorkerThread wt1=new WorkerThread(0,len/numOFThreads,fci,is,file);
        wt1.setName("Worker Thread 1");
        WorkerThread wt2=new WorkerThread(len/numOFThreads+1,2*len/numOFThreads,fci,is,file);
        wt2.setName("Worker Thread 2");
        WorkerThread wt3=new WorkerThread(2*len/numOFThreads+1,3*len/numOFThreads,fci,is,file);
        wt3.setName("Worker Thread 3");
        WorkerThread wt4=new WorkerThread(3*len/numOFThreads+1,4*len/numOFThreads,fci,is,file);
        wt4.setName("Worker Thread 4");
        wt1.start();
        wt1.join();
        wt2.start();
        wt2.join();
        wt3.start();
        wt3.join();
        wt4.start();
        wt4.join();
```