# Read file with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it possible to read a text file by running several threads, so that received line contains information about the thread that read this line?
For now, i can read with one thread:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Deque<String> deque = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            new Thread(new SubReadThread(deque)).start();
        }
        new Thread(new WriteThread(deque)).start();
    }

}

class SubReadThread implements Runnable {
    private final Deque<String> deque;

    public SubReadThread(Deque<String> deque) {
        this.deque = deque;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new     FileInputStream("list.txt"), "UTF8"));
            String line = null;
            String newLine;
            while (true) {

                synchronized (deque) {
                    if (deque.size() < 1) {
                        line = br.readLine();
                        newLine = "#" + (Thread.currentThread().getId() - 9) + " " + line;
                        deque.addLast(newLine);
                        deque.notify();
                    } else {
                        deque.wait();
                    }
                    if (line == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class WriteThread implements Runnable {
    private final Deque<String> deque;
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public WriteThread(Deque<String> deque) {
        this.deque = deque;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String line;

        while (true) {
            synchronized (deque) {
                if (deque.size() > 0) {
                    if ((line = deque.pollFirst()).contains("null")) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        list.add(line);
                        deque.notifyAll();
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        deque.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for(String s : list) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

And expected output something like this:

> #3  line1
>
> #1  line2
>
> #4  line3
>
> #2  line4
>
> ...............

**UPDATE** All that was needed to work properly, move BufferedReader to main method and pass its object to the constructor.

Comment: Yes, but it will be slower as multiple threads attempt to read from a single spindle.

Comment: It is possible to read a file parallely using multiple threads. Are you trying to read the same file n times completely or chunks a large file parallely using one thread per chunk (divide and conquer) to make faster?

Comment: Here the file is a bottleneck, and you are likely going to synchronise threads to read data properly. What's the purpose of doing so?

Comment: Check this one -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885037/multithreading-using-blocking-io-corrupts-file-in-java

Comment: Isnt it more simpler? Files.lines(Paths.get("myFilePath")).parallel() But if it is for experience I think you can achieve this better using RandomAccessFile and i.e. every 10% of the bytes with different thread so you dont have to worry for synchronised blocks that you know each thread will access its own part of data

Comment: shanmuga, I'm trying to read a line with one thread then switch to another thread and read the next line.

Comment: efekctive, yes). i know that the file will be a bottlneck.

Comment: I am deleting the comment. This does not make sense. The only way to make this work is to have a thread read a chunk of file like @HRgiger mentions. And you still need to deal with the HD.

Comment: efekctive, i already solve problem, thx)